# maven build with dockerization if failing

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven, cicd

I'm trying to dockerize my spring boot project with Maven.

Created CI plan using GitHub action.

I am getting the below error while executing the GitHub action. Not sure what I am missing here

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    
    <groupId>com.ads.cre</groupId>
    <artifactId>cre-audit-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>cre-audit-service</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20201115</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.googlecode.json-simple/json-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Swagger API-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!--Unit and Integration test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.19</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>    
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.librepdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>openpdf</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.8</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.10</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>xuggle</groupId>
            <artifactId>xuggle-xuggler</artifactId>
            <version>5.4</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

</dependencies>
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>xuggle repo</id>
    <url>https://files.liferay.com/mirrors/xuggle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/repo/share/java/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>


    <profiles>

        <profile>

            <id>docker</id>

            <build>

                <plugins>

                    <plugin>

                        <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>

                        <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>

                        <configuration>

                            <images>

                                <image>

                                    <name>ads/${project.artifactId}</name>

                                    <run>

                                        <ports>

                                            <port>8600:8080</port>

                                        </ports>

                                    </run>

                                    <build>

                                        <from>openjdk:8u92-jre-alpine</from>

                                        <ports>

                                            <port>8080</port>

                                        </ports>

                                        <assembly>

                                            <basedir>/</basedir>

                                            <inline>

                                                <files>

                                                    <file>

                                                        <source>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</source>

                                                        <outputDirectory>/opt</outputDirectory>

                                                    </file>


                                                </files>



                                            </inline>

                                        </assembly>

                                        <entryPoint>

                                            <shell>java -jar -Dstage=prod
                                                -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
                                                /opt/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar
                                            </shell>

                                        </entryPoint>

                                    </build>

                                </image>

                            </images>

                        </configuration>

                        <executions>

                            <execution>

                                <phase>package</phase>

                                <goals>

                                    <goal>build</goal>

                                </goals>

                            </execution>

                            <execution>

                                <id>pre-integration-test</id>

                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>

                                <goals>

                                    <goal>start</goal>

                                </goals>

                            </execution>

                            <execution>

                                <id>post-integration-test</id>

                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>

                                <goals>

                                    <goal>stop</goal>

                                </goals>

                            </execution>

                        </executions>

                    </plugin>

                </plugins>

            </build>

        </profile>

    </profiles>

</project>
```

Here is my Github Action

This workflow will build a package using Maven and then publish it to GitHub packages when a release is created
For more information see: https://github.com/actions/setup-java/blob/main/docs/advanced-usage.mdapache-maven-with-a-settings-path

name: Docker Image Build

on:
workflow_dispatch:
push:
branches: ['CRE[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+']

jobs:
build:

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
permissions:
  contents: read
  packages: write

steps:
- uses: actions/checkout@v3
- name: Set up QEMU
  uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v3

- name: Set up Docker Buildx
  uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v3

 - name: Set up JDK 8
   uses: actions/setup-java@v3
   with:
     java-version: '8'
     distribution: 'temurin'
     server-id: github  Value of the distributionManagement/repository/id field of the pom.xml
     settings-path: ${{ github.workspace }}  location for the settings.xml file

 - name: Set up Maven
   uses: stCarolas/setup-maven@v4
   with:
     maven-version: '3.5.3'

 - name: Build with Maven
   shell: bash
   run: |
     mvn -v
     mvn -DskipTests -Dstage=prod -B package -X -Pdocker --file pom.xml -s $GITHUB_WORKSPACE/settings.xml
   env:
     GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_PACKAGES}}

 - name: Publish to GitHub Packages Apache Maven
   shell: bash
   run: | 
     docker image tag ads/cre-audit-service:latest ghcr.io/cre-audit/cre-audit-service:qa-latest
     docker image tag ads/cre-audit-service:latest ghcr.io/cre-audit/cre-audit-service:qa-git-commit-${GITHUB_SHA::8}
     docker image tag ads/cre-audit-service:latest ghcr.io/cre-audit/cre-audit-service:qa-${GITHUB_REF*/}
     docker push -a ghcr.io/cre-audit/cre-audit-service
```

Comment: You did not specify the error message you get, please add it to the question. Also,  the `pom.xml ` code would be much more easier to read if you remove the excessive newlines.

Comment: Also, the github-action is incomplete.

Comment: Also, `org.jolokia:docker-maven-plugin` is a **very** outdated plugin, with the last version being released back in 2016. If you want to build your images with a Maven plugin, I strongly encourage to use more recent toolset, such as [io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.fabric8/docker-maven-plugin) or [com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.tools/jib-maven-plugin).